# Need Some Help Regarding Fetching Data from Mysql using explode function

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

In the below script I want to fetch data from mysql using a explode function and also a variable within an explode function.
Here's how I want to get

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$track = "1,2,3";
$i = 1
$trackcount = explode(",",$track);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id='$trackcount['$i']'";
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "{$row['track_name']}";
}
mysql_free_result($retval);
?>
```

This is the code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id='$trackcount[$i]'";
```

I want sql to fetch data from tracks table where `id = $trackcount[$i]`
Whatever the value of `$trackcount[$i]` mysql should fetch but it shows a blank screen.
If I put this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id='$trackcount[1]'";
```

It works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save your $trackcount[$i] in one variable and then pass it in the query as given below

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$track = "1,2,3";
$i = 1;
$trackcount = explode(",",$track);
$id=$trackcount[$i];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id='$id'";
$retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "{$row['track_name']}";
}
mysql_free_result($retval);
?>
```

and one more thing check your previous code with echo of your query and see what is passing ok.

```
echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id='$trackcount['$i']'";//like this
```

problem is with your query

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id='$trackcount['$i']'";//change
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE id='$trackcount[$i]'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would want to use the `IN` operator with this type of query, so for you this would be:-

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `tracks` WHERE `id` in (".$track.");";
```

or, if the $ids are in an array,

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `tracks` WHERE `id` in (".implode( ',', $array ) .");";
```